# Swagger v2 - Enums association

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

Unfortunately I could not locate anything relevant in the [Swagger v2](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md) documentation or in SO, so I am afraid I have to create this new thread.

What I would like to understand is whether it is feasible to associate enums with each other via Swagger. Consider the scenario where our [Definitions](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#definitionsObject) specify a "Status" with two enum properties: "Code" and "Description" as per the below excerpt:

```
"definitions": {
    "Status": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "Code": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": ["01", "02", "03"]
            },
            "Description": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": ["OK", "NOK - Please retry", "NOK - Do not retry"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could we specify that a given "Code" may only be associated to a specific "Description" (e.g. "01" for "OK", "02" for "NOK - Please retry", etc.)?
Obviously, using a property description (which actually acts as an embedded documentation) is not the way to go when  having hundreds of Codes.

Thank you!